# How much can Makarov grow?

Tags: fairy-tail

Makarov, master of fairy tail, has the power to turn into a giant. What size  can he accomplish? Is that the limit of his power or there's more to his skill?

An approximate size is also valid. No need to go into detail as apparently the exact size hasn't been confirmed.

Comment: So far he has shown to be able to turn into a size equal that of a dragon (Acnologia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We never see his size limit, but he can grow himself to the size of Tenrou Island

[image: Makarov Giant Magic]

Another angle from manga

[image: Makarov Giant Magic]

Makarov size compared to a ship

[image]